# python ggplot geom_bar y axis incorrect values

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

`df`:

```
duration status    line
75526    Good      A
75526    Muy buen  B
75546    pas mal   C
75516    loco      D
```

I am plotting via:

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='status',weight='duration',fill='line'),data=df) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Importantly, I am using `stat='identity'` to ensure the y-axis is the column value and not some density measurement. Yet, it is showing incorrect `y-axis` values.

I can compute the maximum `duration` value and I see that this is around the `86,000` mark (i.e 24hrs in seconds). Why is the plot showing seconds in excess of `250,000`?

[image]

Comment: From the information you provide above, i used pandas to use data frame and plot like this: https://s24.postimg.org/rxrz9q3t1/Screen_Shot_2017-03-26_at_9.15.25_PM.png. I don't see any problem, can you explain more?

Comment: There are probably entries in your dataframe with same `status` and same `line` so that their durations get summed for the plot. What do you actually want to happen in this case?

Comment: Bingo @gereleth. Feel free to post an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plot is going to group the dataframe by `status` and `line` and use the sum of durations (aka weights) in every group as the bar height. Some groups must have multiple entries, that's where these extra tall bars come from.

Answer (score 0):

**I am guessing from the incomplete information you have provided that.**

You want to put limit on `y` axis, for that you can use `ylim` method like

`ylim(low=0, high=864000)`

So your command will appear like

`p = ggplot(aes(x='status',weight='duration',fill='line'),data=df) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + ylim(low=0, high=864000)`

Let me know if this is correct.

Cheers